# Read api json response in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to read the following api json response in typescript. I have tried by defining interfaces as shown below. But when reading the values of phone number using loops I am getting value as undefined.

Could some one please help me to parse the below json file in most efficient way.

```
    for(let i=0; i < custdetails.length; i++){
       phnnumber[i] = custdetails[i].phoneNumber;
    }

export interface Address {
    streetAddress: string;
    city: string;
}

export interface PhoneNumber {
    type: string;
    number: string;
}

export interface custdetails{
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: Address[];
    phoneNumber: PhoneNumber[];
}

    [
      {
            "name": "Test name1",
            "age": 30,
            "address": {
                "streetAddress": "2nd test street",
                "city": "London"
            },
            "phoneNumber": [{
                    "type": "home",
                    "number": "111 111-1111"
                },
                {
                    "type": "fax",
                    "number": "222 222-2222"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Test name2",
            "age": 30,
            "address": {
                "streetAddress": "3rd test street",
                "city": "Sydney"
            },
            "phoneNumber": [{
                    "type": "home",
                    "number": "888 888-8888"
                },
                {
                    "type": "fax",
                    "number": "999 999-9999"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: This is NOT a JSON file/text string; this is a JavaScript Object  https://www.json.org/json-en.html  and an object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object - given what you show we have to assume it has already been parsed from a JSON string that was received?

Comment: What is `rootobjarray`? If it's the result of parsing the JSON shown, it would be an array of `custdetails`. That object's `phoneNumber` property is an **array** of `PhoneNumber` objects (and should probably be named `phoneNumber`**`s`**. So `phnnumber[i]` will be an array of `PhoneNumber` objects. It's not clear what's undefined...

Comment: Hi Heretic,
I have misspelled variables. basically I am looking to create an array with list of phone numbers 

phoneNumbers : string[] = []

console.log(phoneNumbers) should give 

[111 111-1111, 222 222-2222, 888 888-8888, 999 999-9999]

Comment: try changing `custdetails` to `Custdetails`.. C in interface to be capital.. I believe you mistyped it

Comment: @AdityaParab, yes I have misspelled variables sorry ab that basically I am looking to create an array with list of phone numbers 
phoneNumbers : string[] = [] 

console.log(phoneNumbers) should give [111 111-1111, 222 222-2222, 888 888-8888, 999 999-9999]

Comment: In your code, it's `phnnumbers`... In any case, the code, as shown, works: https://jsfiddle.net/4y02dLn8/. It may not be in the format you want but that's relatively easy to fix. But you complain about something being undefined...

Comment: Thank you Heretic. I have achieved till here. So on your code when I log console.log(phnnumber[1]); then I get below output
[{
  number: "888 888-8888",
  type: "home"
}, {
  number: "999 999-9999",
  type: "fax"
}]

but when I want to see only number value I tried like this  console.log(phnnumber[1].number); here I see output as undefined. I am sure I am doing something wrong here. Appreciate your help here

Comment: @Devops_Dev: there you go `const output = data.flatMap(d => d.phoneNumber.map(p => p.number));` Where data is the object you've shared above.

Answer (score 1):

You'd simply need to map over the object and extract necessary information.
Since, your phoneNumber is an array located within an array of objects, you'd need to use `.flatMap`.

```
const customerDetails = [
  {
    name: 'Test name1',
    age: 30,
    address: {
      streetAddress: '2nd test street',
      city: 'London',
    },
    phoneNumber: [
      {
        type: 'home',
        number: '111 111-1111',
      },
      {
        type: 'fax',
        number: '222 222-2222',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Test name2',
    age: 30,
    address: {
      streetAddress: '3rd test street',
      city: 'Sydney',
    },
    phoneNumber: [
      {
        type: 'home',
        number: '888 888-8888',
      },
      {
        type: 'fax',
        number: '999 999-9999',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const phoneNumbers = customerDetails
  .flatMap((customer) => customer.phoneNumber.map((pn) => pn.number));

console.log(phoneNumbers); // [ '111 111-1111', '222 222-2222', '888 888-8888', '999 999-9999' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot create the object of interface. Instead of interface use class as shown below:

```
export class Address {
    streetAddress: string;
    city: string;
}

export class PhoneNumber {
    type: string;
    number: string;
}

export class custdetails{
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: Address[];
    phoneNumber: PhoneNumber[];
}
```

And I will recommend to initialize the class property using constructor, so that you should not get undefined.

Comment: Interface is perfectly valid for this, class is not necessary and overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to extract the "number" from "phoneNumber"

```
var phnnumbers = []
for(let i=0; i < custdetails.length; i++){
    phnnumbers = phnnumber.concat(custdetails[i].phoneNumber.map(phone => phone.number))
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `.concat` doesn't modify original array. You'd need to do `phnnumber = phnnumber.concat(....`;

Comment: You are right. I will correct my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first define your model like this,

```js
export class Address {
  constructor(streetAddress: string,
              city: string) {}
}

export class PhoneNumber {
  constructor(type: string,
              number: string) {}
}

export class custdetails {
  constructor(
    name: string,
    age: number,
    address: Address[],
    phoneNumber: PhoneNumber[]
  ) {}
}
```

second, in another class(Datasource class) define values for customer details like this,

```js
export class Datasource {
customerDetails: custdetails =
  [
    {
          "name": "Test name1",
          "age": 30,
          "address": {
              "streetAddress": "2nd test street",
              "city": "London"
          },
          "phoneNumber": [{
                  "type": "home",
                  "number": "111 111-1111"
              },
              {
                  "type": "fax",
                  "number": "222 222-2222"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "Test name2",
          "age": 30,
          "address": {
              "streetAddress": "3rd test street",
              "city": "Sydney"
          },
          "phoneNumber": [{
                  "type": "home",
                  "number": "888 888-8888"
              },
              {
                  "type": "fax",
                  "number": "999 999-9999"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

phoneNumbers = customerDetails
.flatMap((customer) => customer.phoneNumber.map((phone) => phone.number));